# Is It possible to take one enum list and convert it to another?

Tags: c#

I would like to take provided `enum` list and convert it to mine list. I am getting a list from a service Type and then I would like to convert it to mine `FieldTyp` via `DocumentFieldTypeConverter()`

However, this dent work because `enum` is not valid at this point `dic.Add(i, Enum.GetName(rgl, FieldType));`I am trying this for the first time so apologies if this is complete nonsense. Prior to this I have used just switch control but I thought there could be something better

```cs
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var x = new Type().DocumentFieldTypeConverter();
    foreach(var kvp in x) {
      Console.WriteLine($ "{kvp.Key}:   {kvp.Value}");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}

public static class EnumExtension {
  public static Dictionary < int,
  FieldType > DocumentFieldTypeConverter(this Type rglFieldType) {
    var dic = new Dictionary < int,
    FieldType > ();
    var rgl = type.GetType();
    foreach(int i in Enum.GetValues(rgl)) {
      dic.Add(i, Enum.GetName(rgl, FieldType));
    }

    return dic;

  }
}

public enum FieldType {
  Document_Class_Code,
  Document,
  Document_Number,
  DocumentType,
  Passport_Number,
  Invitation_Number,
}

public enum Type {
  Document_Class_Code,
  Document,
  Document_Number,
  DocumentType,
  Passport_Number,
  Invitation_Number,

}
```

Comment: I find a `switch` or a `Dictionary` containing the equivalences to be better options than this. Your solution relies on the fact that both enums are equaly named and ordered, and will break if you change anything on either side.

Comment: I guess you are correct, but wha do you mean a dictionary?

Comment: The `Dictionary<Key, Value>` type...

Comment: yes, but I am already using dictionary so I didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below generic function to convert enums -

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static Dictionary<int, TDestinationType> EnumTypeConverter<TSourceType, TDestinationType>() 
        where TSourceType : struct, IConvertible
        where TDestinationType : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, TDestinationType>();
        var sourceEnum = typeof(TSourceType);
        var sourceValues = Enum.GetValues(sourceEnum);
        foreach (int enumVal in sourceValues)
        {
            var enumString = enumVal.ToString();
            var destinationEnum = Enum.Parse(typeof(TDestinationType), enumString);
            dictionary.Add(enumVal, (TDestinationType)destinationEnum);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Call this from main as -

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enumVals = EnumExtension.EnumTypeConverter<Type, FieldType>();
        foreach (var enumVal in enumVals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{enumVal.Key}:  {enumVal.Value}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Type` is a keyword so I suggest using another name for the 2nd enum.

Here are a few methods, I suggest using the `Enum.TryParse` to check for the conversion.

```
public enum FieldType
{
    Document_Class_Code,
    Document,
    Document_Number,
    DocumentType,
    Passport_Number,
    Invitation_Number,
}

public enum FieldTypeCopy
{
    Document_Class_Code,
    Document,
    Document_Number,
    DocumentType,
    Passport_Number,
    Invitation_Number,

}

FieldType fieldType = FieldType.DocumentType;

// Explicit conversion using the order 
int i = (int)fieldType;
FieldTypeCopy fieldTypeCopy1 = (FieldTypeCopy)i;
Console.WriteLine("Copy 1: " + fieldTypeCopy1.ToString());


// Parse without check
FieldTypeCopy fieldTypeCopy2 = (FieldTypeCopy)Enum.Parse(typeof(FieldType), fieldType.ToString(), true);
Console.WriteLine("Copy 2: " + fieldTypeCopy2.ToString());


// Parse with check
if (Enum.TryParse(fieldType.ToString(), out FieldTypeCopy fieldTypeCopy3))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Copy 3: " + fieldTypeCopy3.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to Parse value to enum");
}
```